# Как убрать значок процента в адресной строке react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

использую react-router-dom для перехода на страницу  деталей про фильм. В пути указываю

```
pathname: `/about/${value.title}`, // {value.title} это название фильма, его я получаю через API.
```

Но когда в названии фильма есть пробел, то в адресной строке он заменяется на значок процента и цифру 20,  например (http://localhost:8080/about/Jojo%20Rabbit, оригинальное название фильма "Jojo Rabbit"). Как можно это исправить или что-то с этим сделать?

Route

```
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/about/:name" children={<ChooseFilm />} />
    </Switch>
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Заменяй пробелы на - или _

Comment: Зачем вам это исправлять? Чем вам это мешает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для СЕО и читабельности рекомендуется заменять пробелы на "-".

```
'Film name'.replace(/ /g,"-");
```

В целом ссылка должна содержать только буквы, то есть все символы названия кроме букв заменяются на "-" и приводятся в нижний регистр.